# NHibernate mapping of generic class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a problem with mapping of generic class.
So I have a class Spec:

```cs
namespace BackOffice.Core.Domains
{
    public abstract class Spec: BaseDomain
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual TypeSpecValue TypeSpecValue { get; set; }
    }

    public enum TypeSpecValue
    {
        StringType = 0,
        DecimalType = 1,
        Booltype = 2
    };
}
```

For this class i have mapping and it work.
Then I have generic class SpecValue:

```cs
namespace BackOffice.Core.Domains
{
    public class SpecValue<T>: BaseDomain where T : Spec
    {
        public virtual T Spec { get; set; }
        public virtual string StrValue { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal NumValue { get; set; }
        public virtual bool BoolValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So I need to map this class. I tried this way after reading [this](http://ayende.com/blog/2951/nhibernate-and-generic-entities) article

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Transport.Core"
                   namespace="BackOffice.Core.Domains">
  <class name="SpecValue`1[BackOffice.Core.Domains.Spec], Transport.Core"  table="spec_value">
    <id name="Id" unsaved-value="0" type="int">
      <column name="id" not-null="true"/>
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="Spec" class="BackOffice.Core.Domains.Spec,Transport.Core" column="spec_id" fetch="join"/>
    <property name="StrValue" type="String">
      <column name="str_value" />
    </property>
    <property name="NumValue" type="Decimal">
      <column name="num_value" />
    </property>
    <property name="BoolValue" type="YesNo">
      <column name="bool_value" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one name="Model" class="BaseModel,Transport.Core" column="model_id" cascade="none" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

What did I wrong? This mapping doesn't work and i don't understand why. I already checked names of assembly and namespace and it's ok. Any suggestions? I will be glad to any help in this question.

Comment: What do you mean by "mapping doesn't work"?

Comment: When i launched the project in Visual Studio, i got an exception with this text: "Association references unmapped class: BackOffice.Core.Domains.SpecValue". But I have mapping for this class and i don't understand why he told me that this class is unmapped

Comment: Can you show your NHibernate initialization code, please?  That is, the code that sets up the `Configuration` object that's used to build session factories?

Comment: Also, somewhere else in your entities you have a relationship to the `SpecValue<T>` class - perhaps it's `many-to-one` or `one-to-many`.  Can you find this relationship and show us the domain class and NHibernate mapping for it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your mapping file is set as an "Embedded Resource" in the properties.  Otherwise the file is not included in the DLL that is built, and NHibernate cannot find it then.